# Redis cluster cannot add nodes

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

There are two redis server. And I have run three redis instances on each server.

When I executed `cluster meet [ip] [port]` to add the cluster nodes, I found I just could add the nods which was running on the same server. Everytime I run this command, it alwasys echo an "OK" for me. But when I use `cluster nodes` to check the nodes list, it always shows like this.

```
172.18.0.155:7010> cluster meet 172.18.0.156 7020
OK
172.18.0.155:7010> cluster nodes
ad829d8b297c79f644f48609f17985c5586b4941 127.0.0.1:7010@17010 myself,master - 0 1540538312000 1 connected
87a8017cfb498e47b6b48f0ad69fc066c466a9c2 172.18.0.156:7020@17020 handshake - 1540538308677 0 0 disconnected
fdf5879554741759aab14eba701dc185b605ac16 127.0.0.1:7012@17012 master - 0 1540538313000 0 connected
ec7b3ecba7a175ddb81f254821243dd469a7f961 127.0.0.1:7011@17011 master - 0 1540538314288 2 connected
```

You can see the nodes status is disconnected. And you can find it will disappare from the list, if you check again about 5s later.

Has anybody meet this problem before? I have no idea how to solve this problem. Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem. I found I had done some mistakes with the `bind` configuration. When I just add one IP which communicate with other nodes for the bind setting. The cluster nodes can add normally.